# Display specific value from PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have a simple foreach loop in PHP. I want to get specific value from that loop. I can get the 1st value with the below code but is it possible to get only 2nd or 3rd value from the same loop. My code to get first value is below,

```
$i = 0;
$colors = array("red","green","blue","yellow"); 
foreach ($colors as $value)
{
  $i++;
  if($i==2) break;
  echo "$value <br>";
}
```

Comment: why you are trying loop, you can get direct like $colors[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) and not [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) to loop through all the `$colors`.  Also, although `break` is not going to be used, you want to `echo` before `break` if you were to use `break` as done with `continue`:

```
$i = 0;
$colors = array("red","green","blue","yellow"); 
foreach ($colors as $value)
{
  $i++;
  if($i==2) {
    echo $value, "<br />";
    continue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but give this a try :

```
       foreach($colors as $value){
           $i++;
            if($i==2){
            echo $value[1].'<br>';//To get the second; $value[2] will get the third
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need a loop if you want to get specific value?

```
$colors = array("red","green","blue","yellow"); 
echo $colors[1]; // 2nd value
echo $colors[2]; // 3rd value
```

Comment: My code is very long and its difficult to explain thats why i choose very simple array. Otherwise i know that in this case i don't need loop. Thanks for your answer :)